# In react, is it possible to render a component inside another component's class function prior to calling render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if the title makes it, but this is my situation:

I have a *ParentComponent* that is a game board. If in a previous session the user was playing and for some reason the page reloads or whatever, there's a history of movements stored on server in order to restore the gameboard state to the previous session state.

To check for previous unfinished game, an */unfinishedgames* node is created on the server with the first movement the user does and updated with every new movement. When the game ends this node is erased from server, so the only way for an /unfinishedgame to exist is if the game has been interrupted.

Now, I want to check for an unfinishedGame everytime ParentComponent is created, in order to prompt the user if it wants to resume it or start a new one. I do this inside my componentDidMount() fetching data from the server and checking if /unfinishedgame exists. If it does not exist, it means the user has ended every previous game; if it does exist it means that I need to prompt the user to resume it.

The thing is that if /unfinishedgame exists, **I can't find a correct place where to prompt the user for input prior to calling render()** on ParentComponent to render the board with the fetched information. My approaches are as follow:

1. Since Im fetching data on `componentDidMount()`, call `setState()` with a property called `{pendingGameState: response.data}` (being response.data the fetched pending game state) and prompt the user with a callback, if the user wants to resume the game, update ParentComponent state with the data inside pendingGame
2. Inside `componentDidMount()` call `setState()` with a property called `{pendingGameState: response.data}`  and then inside `render()` declare a variable called `prompt` that only shows if `this.state.pendingGame` is not null.

These two approaches are as follow:

1.

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(/unfinishedGames)
    .then(response => {
        //if response is not null
        this.setState({
            pendingGameState:response.data
        })
    }, ()=>{
        // render a <UserPrompt> component to prompt the user, if user wants to resume then restore state to previous game's state
        this.setState({pendingGameState})
        })
}
```

2.

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(/unfinishedGames)
    .then(response => {
        //if response is not null
        this.setState({
            pendingGameState:response.data
        });
//Inside render
const prompt = this.state.gamePendingState ? //if true, display a <UserPrompt> that prompts for input, if user wants to resume, update state with pendingGameState.
```

I've tried both approaches and both have flaws:

1. I didn't get a `<UserPrompt>` rendered and displayed on the callback function (I also don't know if its possible)
2. If I take this approach, I will have to call this.setState from within the render() which is not allowed/best practice.

So my question is this:
**Is there a way to render a component inside another component's class function prior to calling render() for the latter? If so, how is this possible** Also, what other approaches could I use for achiving this?

I've also tried returning an anonymous class component inside setState() callback from approach #1, but it didnt display anything either.